# Selenium will not click class id

Tags: selenium

I am trying to have selenium to do the following:

1. Open a website
2. Click on the search box
3. Type "Seattle" in the search box
4. Select the first result from the suggested results

My code fails at Step 2.
The class id for the search box is "class = input_search ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched"

[image: 1]

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://wego.here.com/'
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.input_search.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-empty.ng-touched').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.input_search.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-empty.ng-touched').send_keys('Seattle')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.input_search.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-empty.ng-touched').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION**

Thanks to @Prophet I was able to get the first auto-click and auto-fill done, but when I try to do the same task with a different search box, it does not like it. Please refer to the following code that I added to the existing code:

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.itinerary_item_input_0"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.itinerary_item_input_0"))).send_keys('Chicago')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.itinerary_item_input_0"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

button.btn did work, but not the input.itinerary_item_input_0. Here is the source screenshot:

[image: 2]

Comment: Well first of all check if that class is unique and to be honest never use that type of classes since they are used for design so they propably aren't unique either use xpath to the element or id if availabel

Comment: Please let me know if my answer resolved your problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong locator.
`ng-empty` and `ng-touched` may not be there all the times.
So instead of

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.input_search.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-empty.ng-touched').click()
```

Try using this:

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.input_search').click()
```

`input.input_search` is an unique, stable locator for that element.
Also, you have to add a delay, preferably to use the expected conditions, as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = 'https://wego.here.com/'
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_search"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks! If I understood correctly the first **input** from "input.input_search" locates the input tag in the css and **input_search** is what you can find in the class variable. However, when I try to do the same task with a different search box with a different locator, it does not work the same way so I am wondering if my understanding is correct. Please refer to the edit I made in my post for reference. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I understand what you mean, no. The way to create a correct locator is to find minimal unique combination of element attribute value that will match that element uniquely. So, for this particular element the class **input_search**  will give a minimal unique match for this element exactly. For other elements sometimes you will need to use their **id** value or several **class** values or some other attribute value. Often there will be a need to use some parent element **and** the child element attributes to locate the child element.

Answer (score 1):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get('https://wego.here.com/')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.input_search"))).send_keys("Seattle")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='dropdown_list']/div[1]"))).click()
```

This will select the first option after sending a string to input tag.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```